# Is a variable inside a static function a static variable?

Tags: c, static-methods

Is a variable inside a static function a static variable?

I have a interrupt handler function, which is a static function. And there are some variables in it. I am not sure whether it is necessary to spin lock these variables in the function to prevent multiple access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object defined inside a block (each function definition is a block) does not have static storage duration unless it is declared with `static`.

If it is declared without a storage-class specifier, it has automatic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword, when applied to a local variable in a function, puts it in the process’ data section rather than in stack memory.

This means it will persist beyond its scope and returning an address to a static array or string is defined behaviour.

It has nothing to do with the `static` qualifier on the function declaration, which makes it visible only to the translation unit it appears in.  Variables in a `static` function are not automatically `static` themselves.